# Copy data from one sheet to another to keep a log using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to copy a table with data (from E5 to F18) to another sheet. The goal is to keep a log of the data so the it should always copy to the right of the last filled column.

So far I have the below but it keeps giving me the

> Run-time error “1004”: apliccation-defined or object-defined error

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    With Sheets("Input")
        .Range("E5", .Range("E5").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    End With

    With Sheets("Total")
        .Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part

```
With Sheets("Total")
    .Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End With
```

The secocnd `Range("B2")…` is missing a leading dot. Therfore is the same as

```
With Sheets("Total")
    .Range("B2", ActiveSheet.Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End With
```

And if the `ActiveSheet` is not the same sheet as is `With Sheets("Total")` this errors because you can't build a range out of different sheets.

Change it to

```
With Sheets("Total")
    .Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 2)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End With
```

to make sure both ranges are in the same sheet (and both statements use the `With` block)!